# java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.FilterRegistration"

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

My `build.sbt` file is:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.10.5.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.2.0"

dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.4.4"
)
```

On running `sbt run`, I get this:

> java.lang.SecurityException: class
>   "javax.servlet.FilterRegistration"'s signer information does not match
>   signer information of other classes in the same package

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: Yes I was wondering if you got a solution for this too? Please share :)

Comment: No. I was using Scala for Spark development but then due to sbt issues permanently shifted to PySpark.